# Find two datetimes difference from database in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I have 3 input form which will submit and save data to Database, the forms is :

- **wktu_down** *(this input contain datetime data like **09/17/2017 9:58
  PM** and will store to database with Varchar type data)*
- **wktu_up** *(this is same)*
- **time_report** *(this will contain result from calculation **wktu_up -
  wktu_down**)*

and i want to when i click **time_report** form, its will automatically fill data with the Result, i don't know is i should using Javascript or no.

Models

```
function update_model($data, $id_report){
        $this->db->where('id_report',$id_report);
        $this->db->update('report', $data);
    }

    function get_data($id_report){
       $read= $this->db->query('select * from report where id_report='.$id_report);
        if($read->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($read->result() as $data){
                $hasil[] = array(
                    'id_report'=>$data->id_report,
                    'wktu_down'=>$data->wktu_down,
                    'wktu_up'=>$data->wktu_up,
                    'report_time'=>$data->report_time,
                );
            }
            return $result;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't store date time *with Varchar type data* use datetime type instead

Comment: If i use datetime type, the data will be 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: No just properly format the selected date time before insertion

Comment: Use the datetime type, but when you recieve the data with PHP reformat this date to a `YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` that is the format supported in maybe all DBMS like MySQL, use too PHP to calculate the diff between two dates. Please check [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: oh yeah i get it, but how i make the function?

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime type for the data that receive, but you possibly need to reformat the date value, try with:

```
// I get the format for your example '09/17/2017 9:58 PM'
$wktu_down = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i a', $this->input->post('wktu_down'));
// The var $wktu_down is a DateTime Object and you need use the method format()
echo $wktu_down->('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

To get the diff between two dates use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), like this:

```
// First get the DateTime object of two dates
$wktu_down = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i a', $this->input->post('wktu_down'));
$wktu_up = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i a', $this->input->post('wktu_up'));
// Get the diff
$diff = $wktu_down->diff($wktu_up);
// Format the diff to days
echo $diff->format('%a days');
```

Is possible get the diff in minutes, hours, etc. Check [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Dont forget the second param to the `post()` method, with this you sanitize the value if this contain any value that is a [XSS attack](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post).

```
$this->input->post('wktu_up', TRUE);
```